# Missing menu on Mint host using RDP unless logged in on host console

Tags: linux-mint, remote-desktop, mate-desktop

Using Remote Desktop from a Windows 7 PC to connect to a Mint 17 VM with MATE, the Show Desktop icon displays, but the Menu button does not.  However, if I go to the Linux machine and log in, leave the session logged in, RDP works and the menu displays correctly.

It seems like logging in on the Mint machine starts something that X11RDP does not.

Is there something that I need to configure or add to .xsession so I don't need to be logged into the physical machine to connect via RDP?

Setup:
PC 1: Windows 7 PC using Remote Desktop

PC 2: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running LXDE and VirtualBox as the VM host.  Mint 17 VM guest running X11RDP (from X11RDP-o-Matic).  .xsession contains only one line:  mate-session

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are in remote session: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up menu ...

Start a terminal and `touch .Xauthority`

Logout and Restart your remote desktop connection.